# Is there a word that means "to keep away"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> Mary shifted her hands from the chair to her eyes, 
>   **keeping away** every
>   particle of light.

Is there such word?

Comment: ***Blocking***?

Comment: deflecting?  maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your pick from the following synonyms:

Mary shifted her hands from the chair to her eyes, **thwarting** every particle of light.

Mary shifted her hands from the chair to her eyes, **barricading** every particle of light.

Mary shifted her hands from the chair to her eyes, **occluding** every particle of light.

Mary shifted her hands from the chair to her eyes, **parrying** every particle of light.

Mary shifted her hands from the chair to her eyes, **suppressing** every particle of light.

If I were reading your sentence, in a book, I think, 'suppressing' would read well.

Comment: I have been previously advised to separate offered answers so that they can be upvoted/downvoted separately. At the moment folks cannot distinguish them.

Comment: @NigelJ I am new to English Stack Exchange.  I will heed your guidance on any future answers I provide.  Thank you for the advice.